# Preview of Outllok email via Python

Tags: python, email, smtp

I'm trying to generate a mail in Python in order to send it from Outlook. This is quite easy and no problem.

However, I want to add a feature to the code, I want to show a preview of the mail before sending (and, if possible, be able to modify it).

How can I do it? I've looked for solutions, all of them include other libraries I'm not used to and I don't know how to adapt my code.

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

logIN = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
logIN.starttls()
logIN.login("me@example.com", "Password")

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = "me@example.com"
msg['To'] = "you@example.com"
msg['Subject'] = "Lorem ipsum"

text = msg.as_string()

#Here the preview

logIN.sendmail("me@example.com", "you@example.com", text)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It will highly depend on whether your email contains HTML, or straight up text. If you are just using text (with no HTML), something like a tkinter scrolled text widget would work well. If you are displaying HTML, you will likely want to build this with browser compatibility, either launching a local browser instance if this is a desktop app, or use something like django/flask to host it.

Comment: It's just plain text. Can you give an example please? By using print, I don't know how you can modify the message in an easy way

Comment: Using print you can not (not reliably cross platform atleast).

Comment: You could also just pop open a text editor (similar to how git does it), and watch for changes. Avoiding the need for a GUI at all.